# Ubuntu Python Error

Tags: python, system

It's been months since I used my ubuntu pc. I updated and upgraded it yesterday but when I run `help('modules')`in python I encounter this

[image: error]

I haven't tried using python before I updated my system so I'm not sure if it is caused by the update.

Answer (score 2):

This answer has been previously been asked on SO.  Verbatim...

> Run `python -vv` and repeat your steps. See what module fails to
>   import.
>
> Or install [`faulthandler`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler).
>   Enable it and repeat your steps.

Source: [Python Modules Segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11420059/2353900).

Comment: It's about pangocairo?? Here's the link of the result http://s24.postimg.org/3r4xlfoyt/Screenshot_from_2013_07_30_15_35_12.png

Comment: @markuz There is a bug related at [pangocairo module crashes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pygtk/+bug/1003751). Also you can see more about [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836).

Comment: yeah.. that's what I thought